# Add sources of Retrofit to modify them

Tags: android, retrofit

How to add sources code of Retrofit 2.1.0 to my project? 
Because i need to modify some classes.

I download retrofit sources from https://github.com/square/retrofit

When i try to import as a module (File > New > Import module)

[image]

Comment: download that project files from github then import it as a module

Comment: I already tried this but it seems like it's not an android project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to modify a local checkout of Retrofit, build a jar from that with maven, and then add that to your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't plan to enter in maven but i think you are in the truth.